# java validation checks only working once

Tags: java, validation

```
case 1:
                System.out.println("Please create a Book ID: ");
                String newID = sc.next();
                for (int i = 0; i < myBooks.size(); i++) {
                    if (myBooks.get(i).getBookID().contains(newID)) {
                        System.out.println("This BookID already exists. Please enter a different bookID");
                        sc.next();
                    }
                }
```

// This is a small portion of code from a switch I am using in my program. I'm trying to implement validations and seem to be coming across a few problems. Im trying to allow the user to add a new book to an arrayList, with my program producing a validation check if the input already exists. The code works, but only one time. I understand it may be a loop i need but I'm still learning how to use them.

Comment: could you include a small running example with input in your quesiton. It would make it more easy to solve the problem.

Comment: In one place you have `newID = sc.next()` - in another you have `sc.next()`. Anything look suspicious there?

Comment: I changed the 'sc.next()' to 'newID = sc.next()' but it hasn't fixed it unfortunately.

Comment: You should reset iterator to first element of collection before executing this code

Comment: additionally you might want to reset `i` to `0` to start the check from the beginning again.

Answer (score 0):

You are mixing responsabilities. The for loop tries to detect an already existing book id and requests a new id from the user if the validation fails.

You need two loops:

- an outer loop requesting a new id from the user and terminating if a valid id has been entered
- an inner loop for checking the validity of the entered id